# Calculating the number of neutrons in a sample

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atoms

> Which of the following contains one mole of neutrons?
>
> A. $\pu{1 g}$ of $\ce{^1_1H}$
> B. $\pu{1 g}$ of $\ce{^{12}_6C}$
> C. $\pu{2 g}$ of $\ce{^{24}_{12}Mg}$
> D. $\pu{2 g}$ of $\ce{^{23}_{10}Ne}$

Here's a question which I don't know how to answer. I tried using the equation:

moles=mass/mr

but that did not match the answer given, which is (C). I keep doing 2/24 which doesn't appear to equal 1 mole.

Answer (score 7):

The formula

$$\text{amount of substance} = \frac{\text{mass}}{\text{molar mass}}$$

tells you that you have 1/12 moles of *magnesium*, since you are taking the mass of magnesium (2 g) and dividing by the molecular mass of magnesium (24 g/mol). However, the question is not asking about the number of moles of *magnesium*.

Each magnesium atom has 24 - 12 = 12 neutrons. Consequently, 1/12 moles of magnesium has (1/12)(12) = 1 mole of neutrons.

Answer (score 0):

Answer A has no neutrons
Answer B has 1/12 mole of carbon with 6 moles of neutrons per mole.  So there's only one-half mole of neutrons.
Answer C has 2/24 or 1/12 mole of Mg with 12 moles of neutrons (and 12 moles of protons) per mole of Mg.   12/12 = 1, the answer.
Answer D has 2/23 mole Ne with 23-10 moles of Neutrons per mole of Ne.  So is more than 1 mole of neutrons in the answer.